# How to unit test all code execution paths of Laravel's Cache::remember functionality?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I am a big fan of Laravel's `Cache::remember` functionality and I use it on my service classes like this:

```
/**
 * SummaryService
 */
public function getSummaryData(string $userId)
{
    $summaryCacheKey = $userId . '_summary_cache';
    $summaryCacheLifespanMinutes = config('summary_cache_lifespan_minutes');

    return Cache::remember($summaryCacheKey, $summaryCacheLifespanMinutes, function () use ($userId) {

        $summaryResult = [
            'userExists' => false,
            'data' => [],
        ];

        $user = $this->userRepository->findById($userId);

        if ($user) {

            $summaryResult = [
                'userExists' => true,
                'data' => $this->summaryRepository->getSummaryByUserId($user->id),
            ];

        }

        return $summaryResult;

    });
}
```

This works as expected. If the data is present in the cache, it's returned and if it's not, it's loaded and cached and returned.

Now, I am trying to unit test my `SummaryService` (both execution paths).

The first part where the data is returned via cache is easy to test and it looks like this:

```
public function i_can_load_summary_data_via_cache()
{
    // given
    $userId = 'aaaa45-bbbb-cccc-ddddssswwwdw';

    $expectedResult = [
        'userExists' => true,
        'data' => [ ... ],
    ];

    $summaryCacheKey = $userId . '_summary_cache';
    $summaryCacheLifespanMinutes = config('summary_cache_lifespan_minutes');

    Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
        ->once()
        ->with($summaryCacheKey, $summaryCacheLifespanMinutes, Closure::class)
        ->andReturn($expectedResult);

    // when
    $result = $this->summaryService->getSummaryData($userId);

    // then
    $this->assertSame($expectedResult, $result);
}
```

However, when I try to test scenario where the data is not present in cache and I have to load it (via mocked repositories) like so:

```
public function i_can_load_summary_data_via_database()
{
    // given
    $userId = 'aaaa45-bbbb-cccc-ddddssswwwdw';

    $expectedResult = [
        'userExists' => true,
        'data' => [ ... ],
    ];

    $user = new User();
    $user->id = $userId;

    $summaryCacheKey = $userId . '_summary_cache';
    $summaryCacheLifespanMinutes = 0;

    Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
        ->once()
        ->with($summaryCacheKey, $summaryCacheLifespanMinutes, \Mockery::on(function() use($user) {
            $this->mockedUserRepository
                ->shouldReceive('findById')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn($user);
            $this->mockedSummaryRepository
                ->shouldReceive('getSummaryByUserId')
                ->once()
                ->with($user->id)
                ->andReturn([ ... ]);
        }))
        ->andReturn($expectedResult);

    // when
    $result = $this->summaryService->getSummaryData($userId);

    // then
    $this->assertSame($expectedResult, $result);
}
```

The test is failing:

> No matching handler found for
>   Mockery_3_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::remember('aaaa45-bbbb-cccc-ddddssswwwdw_summary_cache', '10', object(Closure)). Either the method was unexpected or its
>   arguments matched no expected argument list for this method
>
> Objects: ( array (   'Closure' =>   array (
>       'class' => 'Closure',
>       'properties' =>
>       array (
>       ),   ), ))

Any idea on how to test this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I seem to have over complicated this; so I have broken it down and fixed it slightly differently like this.

My service code now looks like this:

```
/**
 * SummaryService
 */

public function getSummaryData(string $userId)
{
    $summaryCacheKey = $userId . '_summary_cache';
    $summaryCacheLifespanMinutes = config('summary_cache_lifespan_minutes');

    return Cache::remember($summaryCacheKey, $summaryCacheLifespanMinutes, function () use ($userId) {
        return $this->loadLiveSummaryData($userId);
    });
}

public function loadLiveSummaryData(string $userId)
{
    $summaryResult = [
        'userExists' => false,
        'data' => [],
    ];

    $user = $this->userRepository->findById($userId);

    if ($user) {

        $summaryResult = [
            'userExists' => true,
            'data' => $this->summaryRepository->getSummaryByUserId($user->id),
        ];

    }

    return $summaryResult;
}
```

and now, I just need to confirm via my unit test that:

1. My service can load cached version and match the call parameters
2. and I can load live data (where i can mock the repos)

Which looks something like this:

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function i_can_load_live_summary_data_for_existing_user()
{
    // given
    $userId = 'aaaa45-bbbb-cccc-ddddssswwwdw';

    $expectedResult = [
        'userExists' => true,
        'data' => [ ... ],
    ];

    $user = new User();
    $user->id = $userId;

    $this->mockedUserRepository
        ->shouldReceive('findById')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($user);

    $this->mockedSummaryRepository
        ->shouldReceive('getSummaryByUserId')
        ->once()
        ->with($user->id)
        ->andReturn([ ... ]);

    // when
    $result = $this->summaryService->loadLiveSummaryData($userId);

    // then
    $this->assertSame($expectedResult, $result);
}

/**
 * @test
 */
public function i_expect_cache_to_be_called_when_loading_summary_data_for_specific_user()
{
    // given
    $userId = 'aaaa45-bbbb-cccc-ddddssswwwdw';

    $expectedResult = [
        'userExists' => true,
        'data' => [ ... ],
    ];

    $summaryCacheKey = $userId . '_summary_cache';
    $summaryCacheLifespanMinutes = 10;

    Cache::shouldReceive('remember')
        ->once()
        ->with($summaryCacheKey, $summaryCacheLifespanMinutes, \Mockery::on(function($value) {
            return is_callable($value);
        }))
        ->andReturn($expectedResult);

    // when
    $result = $this->summaryService->getSummaryData($userId);

    // then
    $this->assertSame($expectedResult, $result);
}
```

Let me know if there was a better or "correct" way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar situation where I wanted to test both paths, when data is returned via the cache and when the callback function is executed.

The key for me was to not use any of the facade mock method (e.g. `Cache::shouldReceive('remember')`) and then the callback code will run.

Seems pretty obvious now :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the proposed solution could be improved further, because actually to make it work, you need to move the code in another method an make it public. So in the end, your are creating a new methond in the public contract of the class only to make it testable. A user of the class could then bypass the cache mecanism and that could lead to detrimental consequences in some cases. We could change this method to protected or private, but then we would have to use Reflection in the test to change the visibility of the method to test it out.

Here is a way to do it without changing the subject of test (the code we are testing). No need to extract a new method or use reflection.

```
$cacheMock = \Mockery::mock(\Illuminate\Cache\Repository::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
    $mock->shouldReceive('remember')
        >once()
        >andReturnUsing(fn (string $key, int $ttl, \Closure $callback) => $callback());
});
```

The `andReturnUsing` is a method that uses a callback that you can use to generate what the method should return. The callback receives the original arguments passed to the `remember` method. In this case I get the the third argument to the `remember` method which in this case is the callback that is executed when there is no cache hit. I then execute the cache callback and return whatever it returns.

Note: I usually prefer passing a `\Illuminate\Cache\Repository` intance to the constructor of my service class rather than using the `\Cache` facade directly inside my service class. I haven't tested it, but I am pretty sure you can use the mocking method directly on the facade instead of using Repository class like I did.